# Guice call init method after instantinating an object

Tags: guice, init, postconstruct

Is it possible to tell Guice to call some method (i.e. init()) after
instantinating an object of given type?

I look for functionality similar to @PostConstruct annotation in EJB 3 (and Spring).

Comment: unfortunately, it looks like the authors of Guice have no intention to add @PostConstruct  https://github.com/google/guice/issues/62#issuecomment-115452493 , which does strongly limit the applicability of Guice (there are workarounds, but those are quite verbose). You might want to look into some other frameworks, like Spring or JEE CDI (eg, Weld)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Actually, it is possible.

You need to define a `TypeListener` to get the functionality going. Something along the lines of the following in your module definition:

```java
bindListener(Matchers.subclassesOf(MyInitClass.class), new TypeListener() {
    @Override
    public <I> void hear(final TypeLiteral<I> typeLiteral, TypeEncounter<I> typeEncounter) {
        typeEncounter.register(new InjectionListener<I>() {
            @Override
            public void afterInjection(Object i) {
                MyInitClass m = (MyInitClass) i;
                m.init();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Also an option is to use GuicyFruit, which claims to support @PostConstruct (see http://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit/), and while it doesn't answer this question, I think it is worth mentioning that if you (solely) use constructor injection, you don't need such functionality as you can do all initialization in the constructor.

Comment: saved my day. @PostConstruct is not supported by guiceyfruit yet

Comment: Matchers.subclassesOf(MyInitClass.class) will actually cause a compile-time error:

"The method bindListener(Matcher<? super TypeLiteral<?>>, TypeListener) in the type AbstractModule is not applicable for the arguments (Matcher<Class>, new TypeListener(){})"


I think you'll have to extend AbstractMatcher to make your code work

Comment: Agreed, this example contains a compilation error. The following blog post describes how to bind listeners in excellent detail: http://developer.vz.net/2012/02/08/extending-guice-2/

Comment: Here you can download GuiceSubclassMatcher utility class to make it work: http://moi.vonos.net/java/guice-listeners/

Comment: Or you can simple change to Matchers.any(), and you check type before calling init().

Comment: Can we do similar thing for shutdown()

Answer (score 65):

You can just add the `@Inject` annotation to your `init()` method. It will get run automatically after the object is instantiated.

Comment: The problem is that this approach does not work if you have optional dependencies, because there is no way to tell guice to call your init() method as the last method as far as I know. IMHO they need @PostConstruct support.

Comment: I am using constructor injection where i have to do some initialization stuff that is depending on other dependencies.

Comment: @OrtwinAngermeier, if I understand you correctly, you can put an `@Inject` annotation on your constructor _and_ on your init method.

Comment: Also not a really good option for abstract methods with @Inject, The TypeListener approach is definitely the way to go to stick with Guice implementations

Answer (score 9):

[guiceyfruit](http://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit/) does what you're after for methods annotated with `@PostConstruct` or implementing spring's `InitializingBean`. It's also possible to write your own listeners to do this. Here's an example that calls a public `init()` method after objects are created.

```
import com.google.inject.*;
import com.google.inject.matcher.*;
import com.google.inject.spi.*;

public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  static class HasInitMethod extends AbstractMatcher<TypeLiteral<?>> {
    public boolean matches(TypeLiteral<?> tpe) {
      try {
        return tpe.getRawType().getMethod("init") != null;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public static final HasInitMethod INSTANCE = new HasInitMethod();
  }

  static class InitInvoker implements InjectionListener {
    public void afterInjection(Object injectee) {
      try {
        injectee.getClass().getMethod("init").invoke(injectee);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        /* do something to handle errors here */
      }
    }
    public static final InitInvoker INSTANCE = new InitInvoker();
  }

  public void configure() {
    bindListener(HasInitMethod.INSTANCE, new TypeListener() {
      public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> type, TypeEncounter<I> encounter) {
        encounter.register(InitInvoker.INSTANCE);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for nice example, just wondering if getMethod("") ever returns null because when it does not find specified method it throws NoSuchMethodException and javadoc doesn't comment on this either.

Answer (score 7):

I like http://code.google.com/p/mycila/wiki/MycilaGuice. This supports Guice 3, other than http://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit.

Comment: Note mycila-guice 3.6 works only with Guice 4.0 but not 4.1, yet; see https://github.com/mycila/guice/issues/11.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to call a method after the construction of an instance, it means the post-construct method call is actually a step of the instance creation. In this case, I would recommend abstract factory design pattern to solve this problem.
The code may look like something like this:

```
class A {
    public A(Dependency1 d1, Dependency2 d2) {...}

    public postConstruct(RuntimeDependency dr) {...}
}

interface AFactory {
    A getInstance(RuntimeDependency dr);
}

class AFactoryImpl implements AFactory {
    @Inject
    public AFactoryImpl(Dependency1 d1, Dependency2 d2) {...}

    A getInstance(RuntimeDependency dr) {
        A a = new A(d1, d2);
        a. postConstruct(dr);
        return a;
    }
}

// in guice module
bind(AFactory.class).to(AFactoryImpl.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

GWizard includes a module (`gwizard-services`) which provides Guava services in a Guice-friendly format. Guava services give you lifecycle management in parallel threads.

https://github.com/stickfigure/gwizard

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to initialize an object using other objects and after both are ready (which is the case if you need to register one with the other and they also depend on each other) you can easily do it like this:

```
public final class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    requestStaticInjection(ApplicationModule.class);
  }

  @Inject
  static void injectApplication(
      ReslSession reslSession,
      Set<Saga> sagas,
      Set<Reaction> reactions
  ) {
    sagas.forEach(reslSession::registerSaga);
    reactions.forEach(reslSession::registerReaction);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on [Geoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094303/6579265) you can "make callable" `@PostConstruct` method:

```
public class GuiceExample {
    @Inject
    private IDataManager dataManager;

    public GuiceExample() {
        System.out.println("Constructor");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        dataManager.printData();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {

            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(IDataManager.class).to(DataManager.class);
                bindListener(HasPostConstructAnnotationMatcher.INSTANCE, new TypeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> type, TypeEncounter<I> encounter) {
                        encounter.register(PostConstructAnnotationInvoker.INSTANCE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        GuiceExample example = injector.getInstance(GuiceExample.class);
    }

    private static class HasPostConstructAnnotationMatcher extends AbstractMatcher<TypeLiteral<?>> {
        private static final HasPostConstructAnnotationMatcher INSTANCE = new HasPostConstructAnnotationMatcher();

        @Override
        public boolean matches(TypeLiteral<?> t) {
            return Arrays.stream(t.getRawType().getDeclaredMethods()).anyMatch(GuiceExample::hasPostConstructAnnotation);
        }

    }

    private static boolean hasPostConstructAnnotation(Method method) {
        Annotation[] declaredAnnotations = method.getAnnotations();
        return Arrays.stream(declaredAnnotations).anyMatch(a -> a.annotationType().equals(PostConstruct.class));
    }

    private static class PostConstructAnnotationInvoker implements InjectionListener<Object> {
        private static final PostConstructAnnotationInvoker INSTANCE = new PostConstructAnnotationInvoker();

        @Override
        public void afterInjection(Object injectee) {
            //@formatter:off
            Arrays.stream(injectee.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
            .filter(GuiceExample::hasPostConstructAnnotation)
            .forEach(m -> {
                try {
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    m.invoke(injectee);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            //@formatter:on
        }

    }

    public static interface IDataManager {
        void printData();
    }

    public static class DataManager implements IDataManager {

        @Override
        public void printData() {
            System.out.println("I print data.");
        }

    }
}
```

Also, you can have multiple `@PostConstruct` method but **you will not know in which order they are going to be invoked**:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    dataManager.printData();
}

@PostConstruct
private void init2() {
    System.out.println("Other init method");
}
```