# guice way to register a listener after calling constructor

Tags: java, guice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guice call init method after instantinating an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093344/guice-call-init-method-after-instantinating-an-object)

I've seen it recommended (notably in Java Concurrency in Practice) to avoid leaking `this` from constructors, and specifically to avoid calling things like `registerListener(this)` until after construction. The suggested workaround is to use a static factory that first calls the constructor and then makes those untrusted external method calls. The constructor would then be (package-)private. Unfortunately, Guice explicitly discourages such factory methods, and I don't believe there's a way to use one while still getting automatic injection in my original class. This feels like a common and natural problem. Is there a straightforward way to do this in Guice?

Comment: Surprised to see this closed as dupe. The possible dupe listed is distinct in that it specifically asks for a way to make Guice call this method automatically, similar to EJB `@PostConstruct`. And @Alex proposed a simple and straightforward solution to my problem that the other OP probably wouldn't have accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using a provider method in your Guice module:

```
@Provides
Listener listener(Colaborator test, Collection<Listener> listeners) {
    Listener newListener = new Listener(test);
    listeners.register(newListener);
    return listener;
}
```

However, this might be a problem for you initialization sequence. Also, if you have a lot of collaborators (constructor parameters) this can become ugly.

There's another way using type listeners. I like the above method better because it's more obvious what your doing. However, sometimes this is better: [Guice call init method after instantinating an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093344/guice-call-init-method-after-instantinating-an-object)

Comment: I like this. It's ugly because every collaborator now has to be in three places (constructor definition, constructor call, and provider definition). But no cost to testability; the duplication is all checked at compile; and it's really obvious what's going on.